Optimal Method for Installing Mautic in a Subfolder
I've managed to install Mautic in a subfolder successfully.
While the usual practice is to install it in the root domain, I chose to preserve the root domain for my website and place Mautic in a separate folder instead.

Root URL: https://www.primeogroup.com/
Subfolder: .../XXX

To achieve this, I modified the .htaccess file by adding "XXX" at the beginning.
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/XXX/(index|index_dev|upgrade/upgrade).php#">

This solution worked well, but after each Mautic update, the .htaccess file gets overwritten. Consequently, I have to reapply the modification after every update.
Do you have a more efficient solution for this scenario?

I have come up with two solutions for my specific need:
1/ Install Mautic on a Subdomain: This approach keeps things clean and avoids conflicts, making management easier.
2/ Add Custom Directives to the Virtual Host Configuration:
<Directory /var/www/html/primeogroup.com/MySubfolder>
    <IfModule authz_core_module>
        <If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/MySubfolder/(index|index_dev|upgrade/upgrade)\.php#">
            Require all granted
        </If>
    </IfModule>
</Directory>

This configuration ensures proper access control for specific files and prevents the directives from being overridden during updates.
